# Bounty expiration problem. Why only seven days?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, expired-bounty

What is the hurry in awarding bounties? Why only seven days?

Sure, let new bounties replace old bounties as far as showing up at the top of the stack. Seven days of extra exposure is plenty.

Let's analogize this, gift cards have a shelf life so that they don't sit on the books for too long. Otherwise you have all these obligations and systemic 'debt' without expiration. I get at least some of the reasons of why they expire.

Currently, in addition to losing exposure you also lose the added benefit afforded someone to take time to answer your question. The bounty requester is losing points regardless. I don't see why the bounty cannot stay on for longer than 7 days.

Bounties should not be indefinite, my new opinion is maybe a life of two months to six months with up to one week of increased exposure granted to bounties.

This has to take into account that answers prior to and after the bounty are handled differently as is-- and I see no reason to change how that is handled. Also, the auto-award in place seems okay. I see no need for changes there either. Does it matter if the points for a good answer are awarded later, I've been on this group of sites for several years. I don't depend on rapid or even timely allocation of points, they just rolled in whenever they came which was fine. One more time, why only seven days? Does anyone depend on getting their points in a week?

However, as an additional hope, I would like to see bounties with no new answers in the bounty period refunded. Again, what harm?

So, before the bounty I had made contributions others felt were helpful and indicated as such giving me some points and certain privileges. Those were summarily revoked for using a feature. If you do not have enough points you become untrusted. This mechanic seems not right and counterproductive.

My experience was this:

I put up a bounty with 105 points.

I received two answers that were not bad, but the answers did not provide me any insight. I had the expectation of more insight from the bounty winner.

I did not end up awarding the bounty.

I was reduced to 5 points-- which means you cannot upvote or comment. I cannot even give the people that ventured an answer an upvote for trying.

So, I am no wiser regarding my question. The site for me is for all intents and purposes 'broken' compared to how I used to use it.

I am a smart, casual user and every time I log in I get reminded of how f*****d over I became. Sorry for you if the language bothers you (not really an apology, I know). I am very angry at how this played out.

I would have happily surrendered those otherwise meaningless points for something of value. I think I didn't receive the value I hoped for due to the short bounty period.

I wouldn't necessarily be making such a stink if it didn't have such a drastic defeaturing effect on the the site. I don't actually care how many points I have, I just try to help when I think I have time and can contribute something useful.

I cannot contribute like I used to and I get p****d off every time I visit. I have, effectively, been punished for hoping to attract an answer from someone smarter than I am. Without changes, I won't ever use that 'feature' again and will actively discourage anyone I know from using a bounty.

Comment: You have a problem with using too much bold

Comment: This would be better on MSO, but your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041104/detect-location-for-a-store-locator-module) seems to be mostly off topic, asking for google search recommendations and reading suggestions and wanting service recommendations, none of which make a suitable SO question. So you likely didn't get a good answer because you didn't start with a good question.

Comment: Asking for **links, product recommendations or offsite resources** such as **search engine queries** is **off topic**. And **no amount of** bolding **will change this**.

Comment: If you feel that the bounty wasn't worth the cost then *you shouldn't have placed the bounty*.

Comment: @BradChesney79 If you want more than 7 days worth of attention, you simply need to cast additional bounties.

Comment: @RobertLongson --that still doesn't change that seven days really isn't long enough. Have you ever issued a bounty? Can you describe your experience?

Comment: @Won't The HTML5 Geolocation API is new, it is implemented differently in most of the popular browsers under the hood, I can't be the only person new to the process of trying to use it to the best of my ability. I went as far as to dig into the source. I will eventually post the answer I hoped to get.

Comment: @Servy After the placement, what I received and the functionality of the site changing as if I had made little to no contribution over the years was a complete surprise and so not worth it. I would love to hear from someone that was happy with placing a bounty of less than 500 points... bonus for low points, casual users with under 500 points for their bounties.

Comment: 700 days won't get you a good answer to a poor question. You can still use the main functionality of the site which is to ask and answer questions, and you can indicate answers that help you by accepting them.

Comment: @BradChesney79 You do realize that your proposal would *dramatically devalue* bounties, not increase their value.  It would mean that the reputation given up would earn one far *less* in exchange, not more, so if your problem is not getting enough for your rep, then you of all people would want to *oppose* a change like this.

Comment: @RobertLongson you can attack the question I had asked with the bounty all day, but the fact is that answers don't just come in seven days when you ask a good question. Take a look, I answer things months and years old. Maybe you only answer or comment on 'new' questions. Good for you...

You also completely skirt the issue of contributing members of the community being 'ham stringed' by the feature-- even if they had asked a good question.

I get it, you don't like my question with the bounty. Do you have anything else to add?

Comment: @Servy How so? It is a lossy system regardless and 1:1 on transfer at best. Rep accrues like normal for people upvoting. More bounties would decrease people's interest in getting more points for answering questions? The one downside is that the best answer has a long time to show up and my answers may not be chosen as best-- same as the rest of stack overflow, unless my answer is the best. I don't share your view point at this time, I would like to understand your logic. Humbly, please share the insight I don't have.

Comment: @BradChesney79 Bounties are paying for attention.  Giving everyone way more attention for each bounty means that each bounty gets that much less attention.  Your bounty would become just one of several thousand, not one in just a dozen or two.

Comment: We have a difference of opinion then. I am okay with being one of many tastier fish for a longer period. You value being one of very few tasty fish if only for a limited length of time.

I had thought of devaluing in the sense of how banks lending money 'creates' more money (your money in the bank ~$100,000 and your money given out to buy a house ~$90,000 = ~$190,000).
I wanted to give someone all my points (those of you with thouands of points may laugh without hurting my feelings) to someone williing to share their HTML5 Geo API secrets.

Comment: If bounties had months of life then there would be so many people using them the feature tab would fill up. Then you would not be a "tastier" fish. You are a fish too far out at sea to be caught on the line, and when some fish near the pier have been caught, you can swim in a little further in, then some more fish are caught, you come further in, then you get caught.

Comment: @James So, I've reconsidered my position. And you're right, bounties get you in the featured tab, longer bounties wouldn't benefit since they are tied to the featured tab-- bounties get you exposure. They do, however, fail if you just want to reward someone taking the time to share their expertise. Also, the ability to increase the value of a question is dependent on contributing to the site. This gives points more value. I've been okay without my slightly elevated privileges these last few weeks. Please, take a look over the revised feature request and point out its brand new shortcomings...

Comment: @BradChesney79 I've rolled your question back, as you've completely changed it. This is not really permitted as such a large change makes comments, answers, and votes obsolete. You also have already had views from users who may not come back and re-read it (etc). I would advise making a new question/feature request altogether. (You can copy/paste the text from the revision history). Or, rollback if you disagree.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I've seen, and most other people's comments and answers I have read, the bounty system works pretty well as it is.

If you have some reason it does not work well, you need to be to the point and explain why. And/or/possibly what ideas you have to improve it.

As it is, I see nothing in your post but some "initial stage" thoughts.
There are no arguments as to *why* you suggest what you do, other than a bounty did not work this time for you.

This is not a valid reason to increase the bounty time.

---

> in addition to losing exposure you also lose the added benefit
>   afforded someone to take time to answer your question.

If it takes someone 7 days to answer then it should be in hardback and published!

> I put up a bounty with 105 points

You didn't.

"between 50 and 500 reputation, in 50-point increments"

> I was reduced to 5 points-- which means you cannot upvote or comment.
>   I cannot even give the people that ventured an answer an upvote for
>   trying.

When I bought a loaf of bread earlier, I knew that when I came out I would have £1.45 less in my wallet. Should I have complained to the manager that my purchase "cost me money"?
Should I take it back after having some toast stating that the loaf I bought is diminishing? I bought 15 slices and it now only has 13?

You knew when you clicked "Yes take 100 of my X rep" that you would be losing that rep. 
It's not like the system took it and ran off laughing.

> So, I am no wiser regarding my question

Link? 
Was the question good enough to receive a good answer?
The better the question, the more likely it is to get a good answer.

I could be wrong, and you might just have been unlucky, but that's all it is, and not "ripped off".

> I am a smart, casual user and every time I log in I get reminded of
>   how f***** over I became. Sorry for you if the language bothers you (not really an apology, I know)

Equally then, sorry if the following bothers you (not really an apology I know, but like you I am going to say it anyway..)

You did not get f***** over whatsoever. You knew what the bounty system was. If you did not, then fool you for spending your rep without some initial reading.

Besides, how can you in the same sentence state "I am a smart" *and* "I got f***** over from a box telling me that it would take 100 rep and I would not get it back and now I cannot use a lot of the site features".

> I would have happily surrendered those otherwise meaningless points
>   for something of value.

If they're so meaningless why moan so much about it?

And you *did* get something of value.
A bounty is not "pay rep to get an answer" it's specifically "pay rep to get exposure & your question placed in an exclusive tab".

You got what you paid for.

> I think I didn't receive the value I hoped for due to the short bounty
>   period.

Rep is not money. It is not the site taking your personal belongings, or some other value from your real life. It is a virtual count of how many upvotes you had on a website, perhaps a few small rewards for editing, or other things.

It's just rep. And you must have surely known what it was all about because you say you are smart.

It's not like the site tricked you, nor do you need to have read the rules or Help Section, because the "start a bounty" function makes it very clear:

"offer X of my own reputation for an answer to this question"
"(this reputation is deducted immediately and cannot be refunded)"
"Are you sure you want to start a bounty of X reputation on this question?"

> I don't actually care how many points I have

Then sincerely, what is the point of your question?
I thought this was about your loss of rep and lack of any return from a bounty?

> I have, effectively, been punished for hoping to attract an answer
>   from someone smarter than I am

Now you are just being really silly.

punish

1. to subject to pain, loss, confinement, death, etc
2. to inflict a penalty for (an offense, fault, etc.)
3. to handle severely or roughly, as in a fight
4. to put to painful exertion

Did any of the above happen to you?

You knew you would lose those "meaningless" points, the system told you clearly, you got 1 weeks exposure which is what you pay for. You received two answers, but you state you are being "punished"?

I think in all honesty, and debate between us apart, you sound like you need to take a week from the sites perhaps?
It's just a website all said and done. I find them annoying at times, niggles here, things I would do differently.
But such is everything in life, learn to work around it.

(I also find the sites pretty dam good too!)

Bounties are what they are, and if you have some good ideas to change them, then you need to put them forward with "reasons" other than "being punished" and "not fair", because you are simply wrong in that sense.

---

> I won't ever use that 'feature' again

That is your choice, but I sincerely see it as sour grapes from a *single* incident where you bounty returned nothing!
This happens for many people - it is a gamble, and there are no guarantees.

> will actively discourage anyone I know from using a bounty.

Well, that is not fair on everyone else. What if you discourage someone who would otherwise have spent 100 rep and gained a fantastic answer?
Just because you got some bad luck?

You were sold a bounty as "this will get you presence". You got what you paid for, and raising the bounty period and warning others off using the bounty system just because you had some bad luck is pretty uncool.

---

---

---

> my new opinion is maybe a life of two months to six months

With such a long period there will be too many bounties in the *featured tab* at one time.

People *will* place more bounties if their question is in the featured tab for months. And as they're in there longer you will have a great deal more bounties in the featured tab.

Then you *lose* exposure, because there are too many of them.
Which makes extending it's live time *pointless*.

The point of a "featured" tab is it's "featured" and something is only a "feature" if it's in a minority.

Also, people tend to answer and help with the ones at the top of the list, so you could have a bounty for 3 months, but it's highly likely it won't get seen until it has a lot less time left anyway.
Again making extending it's live time *pointless*.

> would like to see bounties with no new answers in the bounty period
>   refunded. Again, what harm?

Again, why do it?

If you're going to suggest things, it's prudent to give some solid arguments as to why this should be done/changed/implemented. And telling us the *basic reason* behind your idea is the *least* you should do.

As has been debated before many times, because:

**You are not paying for answers, you are paying for "*exposure*"**

And your question being in the featured tab for 7 days you had your exposure. There is nothing to refund.

What if the question was terrible and unanswerable? Should it then get a refund? Who monitors this, and who decides all this?

Point is, bounties are a non-guanrantee risk, where you put up some of your rep to say "I need an answer" or "this is a really good feature and I want more people to see it".
Often people get no answers, or barely anything in return from the bounty, but this is the risk and it's known this is the case. Don't place bounties if this does not suit you.

> Why only seven days?

The real question I see is: Why not?

If you feel it's not useful, has issue, could be improved, etc, then you need to state that and what change you suggest.
So far you haven't really given any solid reasons why it should be extended, other than it shouldn't be 7 days.

7 days is long enough for users to access it, and that includes it being there through all weekdays and weekends.
It seems to work pretty well to me.

---

---

Your gift card example also does not marry with your argument to increase bounty live time.

A gift card not being used is *not being used*. A bounty is immediately being used, so extending a bounty's live time is increasing what you get for your rep.

It would be like a £10 gift card being eligible to purchase £15 worth of products.

(Also, the gift card shelf life is not because they cannot have have "debt" out there, it's because they make a *lot* of money from them expiring.
100% profit for every card which expires.
In the UK it's hundreds of millions of pounds each year from unused gift cards. In America, it's billions of dollars each year.)

Comment: Boy I love long answers. (But never read them if I scroll down and see a James on it) ;p

Comment: @MARamezani If you have to use the scroll more than twice, you can probably safely assume it has a James on it, specifically one with a belligerent tux...

Comment: Well, I suppose that is it in a nutshell.
You are not paying for answers, you are paying for "exposure"

My feature request is to be able to offer points for an answer, I guess I don't really care about exposure on the site-- I imagine others will find my question the same way I find questions.

I made the request with 105, which minus 100, left me 5. Again, it is punishment because it does cause me inconvenience-- I am no less helpful now. But, in addition to removing the points, it also removed my privileges. Because I used the feature, I should have less privileges?

Comment: Yes, unused gift cards are pennies from heaven.

But, if you had an accounting background, you would realize the impact of having funds just sitting there that you cannot recognize as income & how much it would cost you to have to carry record of those funds indefinitely. That was what I was referring to. Stack Overflow likely doesn't want to have that 'debt' floating (records in a database do have a cost)-- even I recognize the need for these things to have some kind of expiration. Someone is crunching metrics on points. They should have a home, and bounty points are in temporary holding...

Comment: I like you James, I would upvote you-- but, well... I can't do that anymore.

Comment: It sometimes happens with bounties - they carry no guarantee, nor could they. Because a guarantee would require a refund. if we refunded if 0 answers from bounty, *everyone* would just use them all the time. Because then if an answer is received then great they're happy, otherwise they get a refund and nothing is lost. There is no "risk" element so everyone would use them, constantly, feature tab would fill up and then they would be useless, and then no one would use them, and feature tab would become empty, so then everyone would use them again, then.........

Comment: While I may only have a small amount of accountancy knowledge, I do have a "business" background. And I'd be **very** happy if 100,000 people a year wanted to give me £10 and I give them a voucher, with the premise they would spend it later. I'd have £1,000,000 in my bank each year earning me some big fat interest!! Then when 25% don't cash them in (as per real figures show), I've just earned £250,000 for doing nothing! Yes please. There's no chance everyone will cash them in at once, and such businesses have enough in their bank accounts to cover for people using gift cards..

Comment: @James The interest is great, yes-- and on the whole it is great for business. But, points aren't money-- yet they do have value. More than I expected since I am effectively a newbie now.

It probably is easiest, but do you feel the loss of privileges is appropriate for using a feature?

I never said why I liked you while not liking what you say. You help me refine my argument, I like people that help me.

In previous posts you have related points to trust. Let's say I wrote the most perfect question there ever was and had the same results. I am still equated to someone that is untrusted.

Comment: "*do you feel the loss of privileges is appropriate for using a feature*" If you did not want to lose privileges, then do not use all your rep on a bounty. This is how the sites work. As you gain rep you work up through the ranks, if you lose some, you can drop below a privilege threshold. A bounty does not charge you "privileges" it charges you rep, and if that means you drop a rank, then that is an unrelated side-effect which is up to you to consider.

Comment: Payment of some kind is absolutely required, otherwise it's just a question like any other. Rep bounties currently generate the ideal scenario, whereby:   (1) A questioner puts up a payment with their rep, not everyone can do it, and not everyone wants to, which makes it "exclusive" aka "featured"; (2) Answerers have potential to *gain* rep so entices them to provide a good answer. This helps the questioner and other users. If no answer comes, that was the risk. It can be discouraging, but that's how it works out sometimes. Additional bounty life time will not resolve this

Comment: Okay, maybe the bounty system is okay as it is-- maybe a separate feature could be discussed-- just an open reward. Like I said, I don't really care about the 'exposure'. Yes, an answer sooner is better than an answer later. If it is a critical question, I use different channels that deliver as required. -- What I was hoping for was to attach an incentive to answer, a specific reward.

I am going to prepend an amendment with this. Maybe the bounty system is fine-- it is an exposure system for a fast return on investment if any return of value can be had in seven days.

Comment: I may lose on everything I've outlined, and especially with the convention of points equalling privileges. (Changing the rep system to privilege logic could be a lot of resource intensive programming and poorly received by people like you-- and you are more invested than I am. I only help out when the stars align or I feel particularly convicted, thus the 105 rep at best.

Scratch the appending, this question becomes solely about trust being tied to points, in the scope of using features. 'Unrelated side-effect' still doesn't sound like a situation I would like to have caused as a programmer.

Comment: @BradChesney79 **[in my humble opinion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered)** seven days is long enough

Comment: @gnat you didn't get to read this... http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3578f9f1-f485-4b72-b2b9-a30d777b183d/view-source -- or you can wait and see it a second time later, I dare to dive deeper into the unpopular opinions pool!